# Understanding the gcc version and the GLIBC, GLIBCXX versions in more detail

Tags: gcc, glibc, libc, libstdc++

Assume I have the following local gcc, g++ version:

```
$ gcc -v
$ g++ -v
gcc version 6.3.1
```

I don't understanding the relation and meaning of the following compared to my compiler version:

What is this referring to?

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Trying to run a binary and I get this error, what is `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` referring to? why is the number starting with 3?

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
```

What is all this?

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
```

How about the ldd version?

```
ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

I can't link all these version numbers together.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

Answer (score 11):

> I can't link all these version numbers together.

As already mentioned in the comments, the [ABI page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) tells you the relationship between `GLIBCXX_...` and `g++` versions. `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` corresponds to `g++-4.9.0`.

Since you have `g++-6.3.1`, you *should* have a version of `libstdc++.so.6` with `GLIBCXX_3.4.22` in it, but you clearly don't.

It looks like you have *multiple* versions of `libstdc++.so.6`: one in `/lib64` and another in `/usr/lib64`. I am guessing that one of them is old, and shouldn't be on the system at all.

P.S. The version of GLIBC has *nothing* to with your problem, and is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

`GLIBC_` and `GLIBCXX_` symbol versions have no intrinsic relationship.  `GLIBC_` belongs to glibc, and `GLIBCXX_` to libstdc++. libstdc++ can be built against many different glibc versions, and this can result in different `GLIBC_` version references, but the set of `GLIBCXX_` versions is not changed by that.