# How can I build glibcxx 3.4.21 from source?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, libstdc++

When building v8, I encounter the following error

```
./bytecode_builtins_list_generator: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./bytecode_builtins_list_generator)
```

After doing some search, I learn that I have old glibc

```
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

I know for glibc, I can build from source code from [ftp.gnu.org](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.18.tar.gz). However I can't find glibc-3.4.21 there.

So I wonder how can I build glibc-3.4.21 from source code?

---

**FOOTNOTE**
Using `yum` is not ok, because:

1. My Centos is too old
2. I don't want to replace my original glibc

Comment: This is not just glibc, but libstdc++, which only comes with gcc. You need to build not only glibc but a newer version of gcc, too. Building gcc is a challenging task even for an experienced developer. It's twice a hard to build and install it in a way that won't brick your existing system. Your only realistic course of action is to update to the current CentOS (assuming it provides a newer-enough gcc). No other alternatives are available.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OK, so if I want to build a new GCC, which version should I compile, is there a reference table from GLIBCXX version to gcc version?

Comment: I see no reason not to compile the latest version of gcc. I don't know if there's a "reference table" of some kind, if there is one it would be somewhere on gcc's site. This is such a rare, unique situation, it is unlikely that it occurs often enough to have a reference table compiled and prominently published somewhere.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am afraid that my current gcc is not new enough to compile the most recent gcc 10

Comment: Well, so what did I say right at the beginning? "Your only realistic course of action is to update to the current CentOS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After doing some search, I learn that I have old glibc

No, you don't. Your problem has *nothing* to do with GLIBC, and everything to do with `libstdc++.so` (which is too old).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814717/50617) for more detailed explanation.

You need to install a newer version of `libstdc++.so.6`. The good news is that (unlike upgrading GLIBC) upgrading `libstdc++` or installing a copy in your home directory and pointing to that copy with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is generally very simple.