# Where can I find GLIBCXX_3.4.29?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I updated my GCC compiler from the GIT repo to version 11. Now my test code (GoogleTest/GoogleMock) is complaining about GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not being found.
**This is not a duplicate please reopen**
The answers posted in:
*[Understanding the gcc version and the GLIBC, GLIBCXX versions in more detail (2 answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781513/understanding-the-gcc-version-and-the-glibc-glibcxx-versions-in-more-detail)*
doesn't answer the question.

Linker error is:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found`

The output of `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Where can I find 3.4.29?

Comment: I did find tarballs here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc

Comment: I found the answer to my question and posting it here: The problem was caused by the GCC source code build/make install not installing the GLIBCXX_3.4.29 shared library. The GLIBCXX_3.4.29 library was placed under my GCC build directory.

Comment: I fixed the problem by pointing the soft link to the latest GLIBCXX version 3.4.29. Still I would like to know why the GCC make install didn't install the library.

Comment: After soft-link to GLIBCXX 3.4.29: strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
**GLIBCXX_3.4.29**
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

Comment: The question _is_ a duplicate. Once you understand the relationship of GCC version to GLIBCXXX_... it is _trivial_ to deduce that you updated GCC without updating `libsdtd++`.

Comment: @Employed Russian I apologize for the confusion and appreciate the comment.

Comment: @Employed Russian The question was "Where can I find 3.4.29?" even before I made the modification to the original post. I didn't ask about the cause of the linker error, that was obvious.

Comment: For people trying to use Manim: If you're receiving this error, ignore it - the video file was created but you do not have a default player installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After building GCC and installing the binaries, the softlink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 wasn't updated to the latest version. Mine was still pointing to a previous version as mentioned in the comments above. Under GCC build directory I found the GLIBCXX_3.4.29 build directory and copied the library to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and updated the softlink.

Comment: Most likely `make install` installed `libstdc++.so.` into `/usr/local/lib`, which isn't appropriate for your system.

Comment: Yes, it created /usr/local/lib64 directory.

Comment: Interesting. On my system I don't have libstdc++ under x86_64-linux-gnu* (I hate that name by the way... don't know why it can't just simplify into /usr/lib/ as-is). I compiled the most recent gcc from source, and it works, but some old binaries seem to look for a less recent libstdc++. To me this is quite confusing right now. (I did, however had, use another prefix than /usr/ so perhaps this is one reason why my system is confused. It's even stranger because I can compile everything right now, only some programs can not find the proper GLIBCXX it seems.)

Comment: "... and updated the softlink." - that last bit is (part of) what we have `ldconfig` for.

Answer (score 34):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test # Ignore if not ubuntu

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9

sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
```

After this is complete, make sure to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Also, make sure to confirm the necessary dependencies are installed for the right GLIBCXX version.

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

Also try the Quick Solution by @bobka

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH # add to ~/zshrc OR bashrc whatever
```

Comment: Did not work for me on Debian 11

Comment: Does one have to upgrade distro just for this?

Answer (score 11):

### Quick solution

Run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before building your project to fix the linkage issue. Consider adding this line into `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent

### Answer to the question

> Where can I find 3.4.29?

When you were installing gcc from source, i.e. running `sudo make install`, you could have seen a message like this:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib/../lib64
```

Hence, the desired GLIBCXX version is contained in /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (which is a symlink to libstdc++.so.6.0.29, actually). You can verify this by running `strings /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.29`

### Solution explanation

Though you can update symlinks manually, I don't think it is a safe and recommended way. GCC suggest the following options, which are printed just in the same message during installation:

> If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
> in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
> specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
> flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
>
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
>   during execution
> - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
>   during linking
> - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
> - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

Personally, I found modifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH the most convenient way (see **Quick Solution** above)

Answer (score 6):

When I ran

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

I clearly could see GLIBCXX_3.4.29

When I did a search for

```
find / -name "libstdc++.so*"
```

It came back many paths - but specifcally my torch conda environment had a duplicate...

```
/home/jp/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/libstdc++.so
/home/jp/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
/home/jp/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
/home/jp/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

I simply removed the extra file

```
sudo rm /home/jp/miniconda3/envs/torch/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
```

and now  things started working again (for now).

Comment: strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX if you can see your version with this command and have the anaconda environment... try this solution. Worked for me and saved my butt (it was around 3 hours I was sitting to solve this problem). Many thanks to @johndpope

Comment: I couldn't see  GLIBCXX_3.4.29 but I did see an extra libstdc++.so.6... file, deleting the extra file magically got the code to run. I don't what this did, but it worked!

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to build a Dockerfile, I ended up switching from `ubuntu:20.04` to `ubuntu:22.04` as base image to get the correct `GLIBCXX_` version.

Comment: This of course works but it's worth noting that by doing this one can no longer run software built with the new gcc on ubuntu 20.04. If it's a requirement for you to be able to run on older systems then unfortunately this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I went to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ folder, copied libstdc++.so.6.0.29 and pasted it to /home/xx/anaconda3/bin/ and /home/xx/anaconda3/lib and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is, I resolved it by exporting the path.

I had the same error. My case is special since I'm using a shared GPU, which restricts my ability to make modifications to the Conda packages associated with the Conda that is running. However, I do have the capability to install my own packages and export the paths. When I execute Python, it looks in the default Conda path (the path where I don't have write priviledge) rather than the path that I installed these packages.

First I found the libstdc++.so.6.xxxx

`find /home/liang142 -name "libstdc++.so*"`

It's going to return a list

```
/home/liang142/.conda/pkgs/libgcc-5.2.0-0/lib/libstdc++.so
/home/liang142/.conda/pkgs/libgcc-5.2.0-0/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/liang142/.conda/envs/cent7/2020.11-py38/myenv/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so
/home/liang142/.conda/envs/cent7/2020.11-py38/myenv/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/liang142/.conda/envs/cent7/2020.11-py38/myenv/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.29
```

Then I found a version of libstdc++.so.6.xxxx that contain the GLIBCXX_3.4.29 package

`strings /home/liang142/.conda/envs/cent7/2020.11-py38/myenv/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.32 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.29`

Then I just export the path of that specific library (libstdc++.so.6.0.32 for my case)

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/liang142/.conda/envs/cent7/2020.11-py38/myenv/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Here's is the approach that helped me is as follow:
OS:Ubuntu 23.10,
Dlib version: 19.24.2,
I am manually replacing the files temporary unitl this issue get's solved by Dlib
Start with:
`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`
`sudo apt install -y g++-11`
After this enter command:
`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`

This will display all the string in the link|so file
If we see our version i.e. GLIBCXX_3.4.29
Then we can go to the path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ using command
`cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
We can now open the folder usign the command
`xdg-open .`
Once the UI pops up find the file libstdc++.so.6 using search
In my case I got two files

1. libstdc++.so.6
2. libstdc++.so.6.0.32
   I copied them both to the path /anaconda3/envs/my_eny/lib and the files were replaced and working fine

Again to open the folder I used `cd` follwed by `xdg-open .`

OR

You can also create a symbolic link to the files in the x86_64-linux-gnu location
using command

`ln source destination`

Sharing this as it might help someone
Thank you for the opportunity