# Install GLIBCXX_3.4.29 in anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I've seen [Where can I find GLIBCXX_3.4.29?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349875/where-can-i-find-glibcxx-3-4-29)  which doesn't answer my specific question.

I've got `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` according to `strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`. I'm specifically asking how I get it in my anaconda environment. I've got the most recent version of conda, 7.2.0 as per the install instructions [conda libgcc](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/libgcc) but the `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` doesn't meet the version required by some code I'm running

## Addressing comment below

**Would be better to know what you are trying to run**

I'm trying to run some code that uses an in-house `.so` file. I've managed to run it before but I'm guessing that something changed when I updated a library used in generating the `.so` file.

Note: I've tried `git checkout` the library to an older version and rebuilding all of it but I'm still facing the issue.

**How I created the env**

```
conda create -n crannog python=3.6
conda activate crannog
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

[Pastebin of Requirements.txt](https://pastebin.com/T3VXJG1Y)

[Pastebin of conda list](https://pastebin.com/kHtk4jk2)

Comment: Issues like this usually have more to do with channel mixing or environment leakage than having to manipulate libraries. I.e., you may be trying to solve a symptom, not the underlying problem. Would be better to know what you are trying to run, how you created the environment, and maybe even the full `conda list` for your environment.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the `requirements.txt` and the `conda list` results and pasted them in links above. What other information would be useful?

Comment: Looking into this, [the ABI section of GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) indicates only GCC 11 builds with this requirement. No Conda channels build GCC beyond 9.3.0 (GLIBCXX_3.4.28). I think your options are 1) build it yourself 2) [nag Conda Forge maintainers](https://github.com/conda-forge/ctng-compilers-feedstock/issues) to build GCC 11 (and `libstdcxx-ng`) 3) convince whoever is building your .so in your org to build in a more backwards compatible fashion (e.g., do they actually need C++20 features?).

Comment: Ahh, crap. Okay, thanks. Do you know if it's possible for me to make conda look for my system-level package as opposed to the conda one? 

I'll have to look into it... I don't think we need C++20 since last I checked it all worked on C++ 11.

Comment: The GCC 11 compiler now exists on conda-forge, and can be installed as "conda install -c conda-forge gxx_linux-64==11.1.0". It fixes this problem.

Comment: I have no "sudo" rights so I uninstall and installed anaconda with the version that can support Python 3.8.5 (not sure about other versions of Python) and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Using answer from the comments, this worked perfectly:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gxx_linux-64==11.1.0
```

It installs the latest version of GlibC compatible with your Conda environment.

---

To install a specific version of GlibC (as pointed out by @Milad in the comments)

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge gxx_linux-64==XX.YY.Z
```

Comment: this doesn't work.

Comment: Which GLIBCXX version are you missing?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, though `conda install -c conda-forge gxx_linux-64==11.1.0` works for me.

Comment: Great I'll add this info to the answer aswell

Comment: Can confirm it only works with 11.1.0, not the latest one

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error message when installing Tensorflow 2.14 with GPU support in combination with matplotlib in conda. Installing the GlibC library according to the answeres here, which did not work.

I do not know why but what worked for me was switching the orders of importing tensorflow and matplotlib. **First** `import matplotlib` and **then** `import tensorflow as tf`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to update the gxx_linux-64 as mentioned but it didn't find the package. Then I updated my conda by
`conda update -n base -c defaults conda`
and then deactivated my environment and activate the environment again. It worked. I am not sure which step worked.

Comment: I ran both steps, but conda reported everything up to date, so I suspect it is the second step which helps. In any case, thank you.