# How do I run a C++20 program on a Raspberry Pi 1B?

Tags: c++, gcc, raspberry-pi, c++20, armv6

The Raspberry Pi 1B has an armv6 architecture. I have gone to https://github.com/tttapa/docker-arm-cross-toolchain and installed the armv6-rpi-linux-gnueabihf compiler toolchain on a more modern Linux machine. I have then compiled my project and moved the executable to my Raspberry Pi. Executing the program gives

```
./my_executable: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by ./my_executable)
./my_executable: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by ./my_executable)
./my_executable: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.13' not found (required by ./my_executable)
```

Going to [Where can I find GLIBCXX_3.4.29?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349875/where-can-i-find-glibcxx-3-4-29) and following the instructions did not throw up any errors but did not resolve the issue.

Is the answer to build a standalone binary somehow? Or maybe there's a C++20 compiler that runs on the Raspberry Pi?
What else can I try?

Comment: Raspbian bullseye has a g++ 10 package that compiles C++20 programs just fine, at least the simple ones I tried.  So I wouldn't expect any trouble compiling natively, if you want to go that route.  You may run low on memory if you try heavy optimizations, though.

Comment: What OS and version is your RPi running?