# Install gcc-9.5.0 with GLIBCXX_3.4.29?

Tags: gcc, gnuplot, libstdc++

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and need to install a local gcc-9.5.0 (10.x and later does not work) environment and a few dependencies to compile my own software. The environment is loaded via module files with the module command added to the bashrc for comfort. However, when this environment is loaded, other software installed with apt fails with the following message, e.g.:

`gnuplot: <my home folder>/local/gcc/10.5.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.29 not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5)`

If I type `strings <my home folder>/local/gcc/10.5.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` the output is:

`GLIBCXX_3.4  GLIBCXX_3.4.1 GLIBCXX_3.4.2 GLIBCXX_3.4.3 GLIBCXX_3.4.4 GLIBCXX_3.4.5 GLIBCXX_3.4.6 GLIBCXX_3.4.7 GLIBCXX_3.4.8 GLIBCXX_3.4.9 GLIBCXX_3.4.10 GLIBCXX_3.4.11 GLIBCXX_3.4.12 GLIBCXX_3.4.13 GLIBCXX_3.4.14 GLIBCXX_3.4.15 GLIBCXX_3.4.16 GLIBCXX_3.4.17 GLIBCXX_3.4.18 GLIBCXX_3.4.19 GLIBCXX_3.4.20 GLIBCXX_3.4.21 GLIBCXX_3.4.22 GLIBCXX_3.4.23 GLIBCXX_3.4.24 GLIBCXX_3.4.25 GLIBCXX_3.4.26 GLIBCXX_3.4.27 GLIBCXX_3.4.28 GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH`

Is there a way to install gcc-9.5.0 libstdc++ with GLIBCXX_3.4.29?

Looking at the answers in [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349875/where-can-i-find-glibcxx-3-4-29), I tried to build glibc 3.29 and later, but it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

If you install an older glibc - you will break your system. Please dont.

Two options for you:

1. Install gcc 9.x into /opt/gcc-9/ (configure, make install, don't event bother with 3rd stage compiler - that should be enough for you)
2. Use an older Ubuntu docker container to build your program.

Unrelated (?) question: why do you have gnuplot installed locally, and not from `apt`?