# Issue with launching application after updating ElectronJs to version 28.0.0 on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, electron, electron-builder

I updated my ElectronJs version from 27.3.8 to 28.0.0 and encountered an issue where my application no longer launches. The project initializes successfully (creates app), but the application does not proceed further. On Windows, nothing happens in the terminal, while on Linux, the following errors occur:

```bash
1. /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
2. Failed to load module: /home/admin-msk/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
```

My operating systems are Windows and Linux. I have also checked the breakpoints in version 28 of Electron and did not find any changes that could impact my application.

I have verified the dependencies and ensured compatibility with the new Electron version. I have also checked the configuration of the project and confirmed that it matches the requirements of the new Electron version. Additionally, I have attempted to roll back to the previous stable version of Electron and gradually introduce changes to pinpoint the issue.

I expected the application to launch successfully after updating to ElectronJs version 28.0.0 without any major issues.

The project initializes without errors, but the application fails to launch as expected on both Windows and Linux, displaying the mentioned errors.

**How can I resolve this issue and successfully launch the application after updating ElectronJs?**

Comment: Regarding the GLIBCXX_3.4.29 error: I have verified the installed version of GLIBCXX_3.4.29 on my system by running the command 
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX, which returned the following list:
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4.31
GLIBCXX_3.4.32
GLIBCXX_TUNABLES
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Comment: Could you try some of the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349875/where-can-i-find-glibcxx-3-4-29)?

Comment: @arkellys, I wrote that the problem is not specifically in Linux. There is a problem running the email application on both Linux and Windows. About GLIBCXX_3.4.29, I wrote in the comment above that I have the required version of GLIBCXX installed