# ifort: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ifort)

Tags: linker-errors, intel-fortran, libstdc++, intel-oneapi

I am unable to remove the following error as required package is not available in the package manager yum for centos:

```
ifort: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ifort)
```

can anyone help me about it?

I try to find and install libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' by typing:

```
sudo yum install libstdc++.so.6
sudo yum install libstdc++-3.4.21
sudo yum install libstdc++-GLIBCXX_3.4.21
```

with many combination like above.

and could not find it.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. You cannot just blindly invent package names and try if you can install them. libstdc++ is not a package, it is a library inside GCC but can be distributed also by other packages. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557919/what-is-libstdc-so-6-and-glibcxx-3-4-20 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134266/how-to-specify-the-libstdc-so-6-to-use and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401856/libstdc-so-6glibcxx-3-4-2064bit-is-needed-by-skypeforlinux-8-9-0-1-1-x86-6

Comment: Your question may be actually a better fit on the https://unix.stackexchange.com site. You should really read those existing questions and answers. See which details are relevant. You have to tell us the exact versions of your operating system and of your GLIBC and find out which exact libstdc++.so.6 is now being used. Note that OneAPI probly provises its own. Do search the directore where OneAPI is installed to find out which exact libstdc++ is there and find out whether it is the one that is being used when you run `ifort`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the gcc version and the GLIBC, GLIBCXX versions in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781513/understanding-the-gcc-version-and-the-glibc-glibcxx-versions-in-more-detail)

Comment: Ok, I did not realise it speaks about GLIBCXX version, not GLIBC. Nevertheless, the point stands, the versions of the libraries installed is what is relevant. And it is possible that Intel provides its own.