# "version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found" but found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

Tags: postgresql, docker, libstdc++

```
    $ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
```

Yet, when running another application on the same docker container:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so": /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz3.so.4)
```

The `llvvjit.so` file is also present:

```
# ls /usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so
```

I'm using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache
RUN apk add libstdc++ postgresql-client leiningen

WORKDIR /ui-service
COPY . .
CMD ["lein", "ring", "server-headless", "3000"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

What am I missing for postgresql driver to load the shared library, or how can I further debug this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jdbc.postgresql trying to load non-java shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76933048/jdbc-postgresql-trying-to-load-non-java-shared-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30`
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.30`

> Yet when running another application on the same docker container:
> `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so": /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz3.so.4)`

Note that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` are *not* the same.

You likely have two versions of `libstdc++.so.6` installed (never a good idea), one of them is older than the other.

P.S. Using `string` is the wrong way to look for versions. Use `readelf -V /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30` instead.

P.P.S. You tagged this question with the `glibc` tag, but this has *nothing to do* with GLIBC. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814717/50617).

Answer (score 0):

The breakage in this case, including this failure to find a shared library, had nothing to do with the postgresql client.

The problem happened after a debian bullseye -> bookworm migration and was resolved by restarting the postgresql server.