# jdbc.postgresql trying to load non-java shared library?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

The jdbc.postgresql driver says that it is pure-java and platform-independent:

> PostgreSQL® JDBC Driver (pgJDBC for short) allows Java programs to
> connect to a PostgreSQL® database using standard, database independent
> Java code. Is an open source JDBC driver written in Pure Java (Type
> 4), and communicates in the PostgreSQL® native network protocol.
> Because of this, the driver is platform independent; once compiled,
> the driver can be used on any system.

This looks great. But when I put my clojure app inside a docker container, the jdbc posgresql fails:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/llvmjit.so": /lib/x86_64-
linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz3.so.4)
           QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse
           QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults
            QueryExecutorImpl.java:368 org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute                               
                  PgStatement.java:498 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal
                  PgStatement.java:415 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute                                        
          PgPreparedStatement.java:190 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags
          PgPreparedStatement.java:134 org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery
                         jdbc.clj:1090 clojure.java.jdbc/execute-query-with-params       
                         jdbc.clj:1084 clojure.java.jdbc/execute-query-with-params  
                         jdbc.clj:1113 clojure.java.jdbc/db-query-with-resultset*           
                         jdbc.clj:1093 clojure.java.jdbc/db-query-with-resultset*          
                         jdbc.clj:1182 clojure.java.jdbc/query   
                         jdbc.clj:1144 clojure.java.jdbc/query                                                        
                         jdbc.clj:1160 clojure.java.jdbc/query
```

If the JDBC driver supposed to be pure java, why is it trying to look up some non-java shared library? Why is it specifically trying to load a postgresql 13 shared object library (my system only has postgresql-15)?

The queries appear to work from a local psql client:

```
█[debian-x1-7th][~][130]$ PGPASSWORD=REDACTED psql -h localhost -p 5432 REDACTED REDACTED
psql (15.3 (Debian 15.3-0+deb12u1), server 13.10 (Debian 13.10-0+deb11u1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

REDACTED=> select * from activity limit 10;
REDACTED=> select * from activity limit 10;
REDACTED=> select COUNT(*) from activity limit 10;
 count  
--------
 742854
(1 row)

REDACTED=>
```

jdbc URI parameters:

```
(def pg-db {:dbtype "postgresql"
            :port 5432
            :host "localhost"
            :user "REDACTED"
            :dbname "REDACTED"
            :password "REDACTED"})
```

Edit: It appears that simple queries that return a small number of rows actually complete successfully, but heavier queries with bigger output sizes fail with this error.

Comment: Please edit your post and include your jdbc url.

Comment: Please try adding `:ssl true`, per [use](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/).

Comment: It doesn't appear to have been an issue related to the JDBC driver or the network, I can reproduce it with psql on the same machine hosting the postgresql server.

Answer (score 5):

The JDBC postgres driver docs aren't lying to you. That error is **from the postgres server itself**, not from the JDBC driver. The entire postgres installation is broken (try running the `psql` tool from the command line, for example, you'll get the same error).

There aren't enough details in your question to give you a hint about how to solve the bug. However, the actual question is: "Why does the postgres JDBC driver require this 'non-java shared library'" and the answer is: It doesn't require that library; your postgres server does, though.

Comment: It's strange but I actually tried the psql client locally and it worked (edited question)

Comment: I was trying a much simpler query, which worked both from within psql and JDBC. But a larger query failed. This confirms to me that the error is on the server side. Thanks!

Comment: The problem happened after a debian bullseye -> bookworm migration and was resolved by restarting the postgresql server.